# How can I prevent saving document in libreoffice?

Tags: python, plugins, save, document, libreoffice

I am working on plugin development in LibreOffice. I need a plugin that prevents it from saving the file if it hasn't selected a tag when saving the file. It can also be done for office on Windows.

Comment: Remind me never to use your extension, because I need to be able to save files! :) Seriously, disabling core features of LibreOffice may be possible but can turn out to be a bad experience for the user. There are many ways to call the Save or Save As or Export features of LibreOffice, and do you really want to hack all of them to prevent them from working as intended?

Comment: Having said that, here is a discussion about python-uno code that listens for save events (code in both the question and my answer): https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-get-save-listener-event-to-python-code/53402. If you want to dig into this further, ask more about it and I can provide details.

Comment: Or post the question at ask.libreoffice.org, which is where most of the python-uno experts hang out.