# Preventing the save operation from within the libreoffice plugin

Tags: python, libreoffice

I try to learn some event reflex extensions of LibreOffice. Catching events(like Save, SaveAs etc.) and after that getting some information about caught event(like flags, member variables etc.) and blocking event routine that I filtered is what I want to do. For example, the function has been caught SaveAs event and if the function want to prevent SaveAs routine, it has to set related flag or member variable of caught event. I have found some example python scripts from [libreofficehelp](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/sbasic/python/python_document_events.html).

The example used `XDocumentEventListener` from `com.sun.star.document`. And the example used following 2 functions for catching,

```
    def listen(self, *args):  # OnLoad/OnNew at the earliest
        """ Start doc. events monitoring """
        self.doc.addDocumentEventListener(self)
        Console.log("INFO", "Document events are being logged", True)
```

```
    def documentEventOccured(self, event: DocumentEvent):
        """ Intercepts all doc. events """
        #self.setCell(event.Source, event.EventName) # only for Calc docs
        Console.log("DEBUG",
            event.EventName+" in "+self.Filename,
            False)
```

I tried to find documents about `XDocumentEventListener`. Unfortunately, I could not find an explanatory and detailed document.

In addition, similar process can be done on the Microsoft Office side below:

```
private void Application_DocumentBeforeSave(Word.Document doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
{
  ...
  Cancel = true;
  return;
}
```

How can I find related document and where from ? Or may someone give me some information ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in Basic from https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/prevent-save-in-calc-with-a-macro/3772 :

> In Menu/Tools/Customize/Events you can assign a macro to “Save document” event.

```
function onsave(oEvent as object)
    oEvent.Source.disableSetModified()
    onsave=false
end function
```

From that same comment:

> This prevent saving the document until you close the document.
> Then appears the question “Document was modified. Save, discard or cancel?”
> If you click “save” the document will be saved anyway.

Perhaps you could also add a handler for the `Close Document` event.

As mentioned in my comment to [the question that seems suspiciously similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72361588/how-can-i-prevent-saving-document-in-libreoffice), this would potentially make LibreOffice very difficult for the user, so I wouldn't recommend it, and that's probably why there is so little information.